# SBT into wrong directory

Tags: scala, sbt

I have just started with Scala and am trying to setup the Simple Build Tool (SBT). Having followed all the instructions for running in cygwin I have it up and running but am experiencing one strange behaviour. The class files are compiled into `target\scala-2.8.1\classes` instead of simply `target\classes`. If I use a different version of scala then the directory name reflects that version.

Any reason why this happening? I am aware I can configure the build but surely this isn't the normal behaviour?

Comment: What you miss is that classes produced by each Scala version is incompatible with all other Scala version, with the sole exception of Scala 2.8.0 and 2.8.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour. sbt enables building against multiple versions of scala, [as described on the wiki](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Loader).

**Edit**
Regarding the question in your comment: you can do this by overriding the `outputpath` method:

```
override def outputPath = "target"
```

which will compile your code into `target/classes`, without the scala build version. 
It may also be useful to check the [paths page](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Paths) on the sbt wiki for this, as well as the [ProjectPaths](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/blob/master/sbt/src/main/scala/sbt/ProjectPaths.scala) source code on github to see a list with all configurable options.

Comment: So it is...must be a reason for it I'm not seeing yet. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming it is useful for something, is there a way of building to that directory as well as target/classes?